# Unable to display and update data from linked database into table in ASP.NET Core

Tags: sql-server, database, asp.net-core, foreach, model

I'm new to ASP.NET Core and I'm working on a student management web app using razor pages. I created a test database in Microsoft SQL Server containing a table called `JITStudents` which I'm trying to display on a table on the students "Registration" and "Manage Student" pages.

I created a `Models` folder in which I have a class `JITStudents`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

namespace JUI21.Models

{
    public class JITStudents
    {
        [Key]
        public int StudentID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string StdfirstName { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        public string StdlastName { get; set; }
  
        public int StdBirthDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Stdgender { get; set; }

        public string StdPhone { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string StdEmail { get; set; }

        public string StdAddress { get; set; }
        public string StdCity { get; set; }
        public string StdState { get; set; }
        public string StdZipCode { get; set; }
        public string StdStatus { get; set; }
       
        public List<JITStudents> GetJITStudentsParameters()
        {
            List<JITStudents> JITStudentsParameterList = new List<JITStudents>();

            string connectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-IK1GLFJ\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=JITStuRegistry;Integrated Security=True";

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            string sqlQuery = "select JITStudentID, StdfirstName, StdlastName, StdBirthDate, Stdgender, StdPhone, StdEmail" +
                              "StdAddress, StdCity, StdState, StdZipCode, StdStatus";

            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr !=null)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    JITStudents JITStudentsParameter = new JITStudents();

                    JITStudentsParameter.StudentID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["StudentID"]);
                    JITStudentsParameter.StdfirstName = dr["StdfirstName"].ToString();
                    JITStudentsParameter.StdlastName = dr["StdlastName"].ToString();
                    JITStudentsParameter.StdBirthDate = Convert.ToInt32(dr["StdBirthDate"]);
                    JITStudentsParameter.Stdgender = dr["Stdgender"].ToString();
                    JITStudentsParameter.StdPhone = dr["StdPhone"].ToString();
                    JITStudentsParameter.StdEmail = dr["StdEmail"].ToString();
                    JITStudentsParameter.StdAddress = dr["StdAddress"].ToString();
                    JITStudentsParameter.StdCity = dr["StdCity"].ToString();
                    JITStudentsParameter.StdState = dr["StdState"].ToString();
                    JITStudentsParameter.StdZipCode = dr["StdZipCode"].ToString();
                    JITStudentsParameter.StdStatus = dr["StdStatus"].ToString();

                    JITStudentsParameterList.Add(JITStudentsParameter);
                }
            }
            return JITStudentsParameterList;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, to the `ManageStudent.cshtml.cs` file I added the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using JUI21.Models;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

namespace JUI21.Pages.Student
{
    public class ManageStudentModel : PageModel
    {
        public List<JITStudents> JITStudentsParameterList = new List<JITStudents>();

        public void OnGet()
        {
            JITStudents jitstudents = new JITStudents();

            JITStudentsParameterList = jitstudents.GetJITStudentsParameters();
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately for me, trying to use the foreach (var JITStudents in Model.JITStudentsParameterList) statement to display the data on my table in the ManageStudent.cshtml as seen in the code below:

```
@page
@model JUI21.Pages.Student.ManageStudentModel
@{
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title brand-text font-weight-bold ">Manage Student</h3>

                <div class="card-tools">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="width: 150px;">
                        <input type="text" name="table_search" class="form-control float-right" placeholder="Search">

                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.card-header -->
            <div class="card-body table-responsive p-0">
                <table class="table table-hover text-nowrap">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>StudentID</th>
                            <th>StdfirstName</th>
                            <th>StdlastName</th>
                            <th>StdbirthDate</th>
                            <th>StdGender</th>
                            <th>StdPhone</th>
                            <th>StdEmail</th>
                            <th>StdAddress</th>
                            <th>StdCity</th>
                            <th>StdState</th>
                            <th>StdzipCode</th>
                            <th>StdStatus</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                
                     <tbody>
                           @{
                        if (Model !=null)

                        {
                            foreach (var JITStudents in Model.JITStudentsParameterList)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td> @JITStudents.StudentID</td>
                                    <td> @JITStudents.StdfirstName</td>
                                    <td> @JITStudents.StdlastName</td>
                                    <td> @JITStudents.StdBirthDate</td>
                                    <td> @JITStudents.Stdgender</td>
                                    <td> @JITStudents.StdPhone</td>
                                    <td> @JITStudents.StdEmail</td>
                                    <td> @JITStudents.StdAddress</td>
                                    <td> @JITStudents.StdCity</td>
                                    <td> @JITStudents.StdState</td>
                                    <td> @JITStudents.StdZipCode</td>
                                    <td> @JITStudents.StdStatus</td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        }
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <!-- /.card-body -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.card -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Results in an error

> 'ManageStudentModel' does not contain a definition for 'JITStudentsParameterList' and no accessible extension method 'JITStudentsParameterList' accepting a first argument of type 'ManageStudentModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

For the registration page where I repeated the same data display process the error I get when clicking on the page from the nav menu is

> One or more compilation references may be missing. If you're seeing this in a published application, set 'CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory' to true in your project file to ensure files in the refs directory are published.
>
> The type or namespace name 'RegistrationModel' does not exist in the namespace 'JUI21.Pages.Student' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> The type or namespace name 'RegistrationModel' does not exist in the namespace 'JUI21.Pages.Student' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> The type or namespace name 'RegistrationModel' does not exist in the namespace 'JUI21.Pages.Student' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> The type or namespace name 'RegistrationModel' does not exist in the namespace 'JUI21.Pages.Student' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

What did I do wrong how can I get it to work please help. For now, I'm just trying to display the records from the database on the table. If I can do so successfully, I'll like to move on to adding, updating, and deleting records on the database through the web app. The entire layout is complete and runs well when I manually enter records into the Html page like so;

```
@page
@model JUI21.Pages.Student.ManageStudentModel
@{
}


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title brand-text font-weight-bold ">Manage Student</h3>

                <div class="card-tools">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="width: 150px;">
                        <input type="text" name="table_search" class="form-control float-right" placeholder="Search">

                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.card-header -->
            <div class="card-body table-responsive p-0">
                <table class="table table-hover text-nowrap">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>StudentID</th>
                            <th>StdfirstName</th>
                            <th>StdlastName</th>
                            <th>StdbirthDate</th>
                            <th>StdGender</th>
                            <th>StdPhone</th>
                            <th>StdEmail</th>
                            <th>StdAddress</th>
                            <th>StdCity</th>
                            <th>StdState</th>
                            <th>StdzipCode</th>
                            <th>StdStatus</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                
                     <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td>183</td>
                            <td>John</td>
                            <td>Doe</td>
                            <td>04-24-1984</td>
                            <td>Male</td>
                            <td>505-875-1952</td>
                            <td>jdoe@gmail.com</td>
                            <td>15 Private Dr</td>
                            <td>Houston</td>
                            <td>TX</td>
                            <td>79105</td>
                            <td><span class="tag tag-success">Approved</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>219</td>
                            <td>Alexander</td>
                            <td>Pierce</td>
                            <td>9-14-1989</td>
                            <td>Male</td>
                            <td>702-875-1952</td>
                            <td>apierce@gmail.com</td>
                            <td>415 Gallileo St</td>
                            <td>Dallas</td>
                            <td>TX</td>
                            <td>79805</td>
                            <td><span class="tag tag-warning">Pending</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>657</td>
                            <td>Bob</td>
                            <td>Doe</td>
                            <td>04-24-1994</td>
                            <td>Male</td>
                            <td>813-891-7952</td>
                            <td>bdoe@gmail.com</td>
                            <td>1852 Mango Dr</td>
                            <td>Houston</td>
                            <td>TX</td>
                            <td>79105</td>
                            <td><span class="tag tag-primary">Approved</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>175</td>
                            <td>Caroline</td>
                            <td>Fru</td>
                            <td>12-07-1990</td>
                            <td>Female</td>
                            <td>818-952-0297</td>
                            <td>caro22@aol.com</td>
                            <td>5823 N Sunset Blvd</td>
                            <td>Los Angeles</td>
                            <td>CA</td>
                            <td>98716</td>
                            <td><span class="tag tag-danger">Denied</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>183</td>
                            <td>Jane</td>
                            <td>Doe</td>
                            <td>05-15-1988</td>
                            <td>Feale</td>
                            <td>575-435-0962</td>
                            <td>j8ne@gmail.com</td>
                            <td>115 4th St</td>
                            <td>San Antonio</td>
                            <td>TX</td>
                            <td>79415</td>
                            <td><span class="tag tag-success">Approved</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>219</td>
                            <td>Alex</td>
                            <td>Devoe</td>
                            <td>2-14-1984</td>
                            <td>Male</td>
                            <td>212-672-2846</td>
                            <td>adevoe@hotmail.com</td>
                            <td>8 Ball St</td>
                            <td>Silver Spring</td>
                            <td>MD</td>
                            <td>20104</td>
                            <td><span class="tag tag-warning">Pending</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>657</td>
                            <td>Olivia</td>
                            <td>Batupe</td>
                            <td>01-29-1978</td>
                            <td>Female</td>
                            <td>202-443-7869</td>
                            <td>olib1@gmail.com</td>
                            <td>4 Mimbo Dr</td>
                            <td>Laural</td>
                            <td>MD</td>
                            <td>20105</td>
                            <td><span class="tag tag-primary">Approved</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>175</td>
                            <td>Michael</td>
                            <td>Landis</td>
                            <td>08-07-1989</td>
                            <td>Male</td>
                            <td>505-322-8088</td>
                            <td>Mikel@aol.com</td>
                            <td>200 Mountain View Dr</td>
                            <td>Rio Rancho</td>
                            <td>NM</td>
                            <td>87144</td>
                            <td><span class="tag tag-danger">Denied</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <!-- /.card-body -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.card -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is what it looks like when I run it;
[UI image with manual entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47z06.png)

I'll like to get the app to look like this displaying records from the database instead.

Thanks for your help, anyone who can. I need guidance.

Comment: Hi @Patrice Fote, I have tested your code and works fine without these errors. Did you get the error in development environment? Could you please debug the code and tell us Which line makes the first error? For the second error, please check your `Registration.cshtml` if it locates in `JUI21.Pages.Student` folder or check the namespace of `Registration.cshtml.cs`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. The first error comes from line 47 on the Html file, where I use @foreach (var JITStudents in Model.JITStudentsParameterList)